# What is the difference between self.variable and self->variable?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have seen accessing variable in iphone sdk  with -> or . symbol.Which one is the best?what is the difference between self.variable and self->variable?

Comment: For an explanation of what happens when using the dot notation and properties with synthesize, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576593/objective-c-memory-management-of-instance-members/8576760#8576760)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot-notation goes through the accessor, the arrow notation goes directly to the instance variable. Try this code:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSInteger bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar;

- (void) setBar: (NSInteger) newBar
{
    NSLog(@"Setting new bar.");
    bar = newBar;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    self->bar = 5; // doesn’t log anything
    self.bar  = 6; // logs
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: “Log” is writing to the console using `NSLog`.

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation will use the properties getter/setter methods - so dependant on what you have declared the variable may be retained or assigned or you can specify your own getter / setter methods to do extra work whenever that property is set.

self-> is a pointer reference to self. Which accesses the var directly. I personally don't see the point in using it in obj c as just 'var on it's own' will have the same effect.

ps. There are a ton of other questions/answers on this exact subject here on SO.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126309/difference-between-dot-notation-and-in-objective-c) one

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c) one

Answer (score 0):

`self.var`means you declare a property for var,supposing like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id var;
```

it in fact calls [self var] for `self.var`.

While `self->var` just gets the member value of self instance like you do in C++ or else.