# I can't read and write variables from outside the class the made in?

Tags: objective-c

This is the code i used to get two date variables from AppDelegate. But the variables never contain anything they just seem to be blank. My question is am i doing something wrong with the code?

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [appDelegate->enterForgroundDate timeIntervalSinceDate:appDelegate->enterBackgroundDate];
```

Comment: Can you share how you declare your variables in your AppDelegate

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Define your variables in your `AppDelegate.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *enterForgroundDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *enterBackgroundDate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL testBool;
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [appDelegate.enterForgroundDate timeIntervalSinceDate:appDelegate.enterBackgroundDate];
NSLog(@"appDelegate: %i", appDelegate.testBool );
```

For more information about the dot-notation or arrow-notation see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427237/what-is-the-difference-between-self-variable-and-self-variable)

Comment: Ok so I've implemented this in exactly as you have but if i try and access BOOL variable in this way it just seams to set them to NO even if they are YES in the app delegate class. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a BOOL. It should just work in the same way. Let me know if it works for you